# Toc over multiple pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

my table of contents is very long, so it begins on page 2 and doesn't split when the page is full. How can I achieve an automatic split? I don't want to split it manually as I'm still working in the document.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}\alph{paragraph})}
\renewcommand*{\thesubparagraph}{(\arabic{subparagraph})}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subparagraphnumdepth}% number until subparagraph
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subparagraphtocdepth}% show until subparagraph in ToC
%\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{10cm}
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10cm}
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10cm}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}% no parskip in ToC
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}% no skip after ToC title
}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=0cm]{chapter}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=0.7cm]{section}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=1.4cm]{default}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=2.1cm]{default}{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=2.8cm]{default}{paragraph}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=0.7cm,indent=3.5cm]{default}{subparagraph}
```

Comment: all standard tables of contents styles will break over pages so you have some local code that is stopping that. As always, you should include a complete small document that shows the problem.